# How to run Multiples Task on FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created two tasks to write data on the firebase datbase

```
class EventDataAddingTask implements Continuation<User, Task<Boolean>> {
        @Override
        public Task<Boolean> then(Task<User> task) {
            final TaskCompletionSource<Boolean> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
            mUserEventsRefrence.child(user.getUid()).setValue(addEditEventData)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                tcs.setResult(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception error) {
                            tcs.setResult(false);
                            tcs.setException(error);
                        }
                    });
            return tcs.getTask();
        }
    }



class UserPaymentAddingTask implements Continuation<User, Task<Boolean>> {
        @Override
        public Task<Boolean> then(Task<User> task) {
            final TaskCompletionSource<Boolean> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
            mUserPaymentDetailsRefrence.child(user.getUid()).setValue(addEditUserPaymentData)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                tcs.setResult(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception error) {
                    tcs.setResult(false);
                    tcs.setException(error);
                }
            });
            return tcs.getTask();
        }
    }
```

I do not know how to run these two tasks so that when one task is completed and other run automatically and show message to user when both task has completed successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Play Services Task API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) provides a way to [chain](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#chaining) tasks together sequentially using [continueWithTask()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#continueWithTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation%3CTResult,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3CTContinuationResult%3E%3E)).